# How to avoid running "test" again when running "install"

Tags: java, maven

In our maven project we have a couple of targets: `clean`, `test`, and `install`.

If I run `mvn clean install`, it runs `test` which is a prerequisite for `install`. If I then run `mvn clean install` again without any code changes, it runs `test` again.

How can I make it smart enough to avoid unnecessarily running `test` the 2nd time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage two useful properties to manipulate test cases

```
# Skip test cases compilation
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip install

# Compile test cases but not execute them
mvn -DskipTests install
```

However, if you want maven to only run test that have changed then you cannot do that. This is one of the very handy things that Gradle provides over Maven.

You can take a look at this site:
https://dzone.com/articles/reducing-test-times-only
where the guy created a poc, although it is a workaround (not provided by maven), so I think you want Gradle smart things for your case.

Answer (score 1):

This skips tests

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: And then you can compiling and validating everything twice for what benefit?

Answer (score 1):

Every Maven phase runs every proceeding Maven phase of the lifecycle except `clean`. i.e. `test` runs validate, compile, and test.

So since `install` *already* runs every proceeding phase, including `test`, don't bother calling `mvn test` explicitly. If a test fails, it won't proceed any further.

tl;dr: what you want is

```
mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can tell maven to include/exclude test via arguments:

```
# Exclude one test class, by using the explanation mark (!)
mvn clean install -Dtest=!LegacyTest
# Exclude one test method
mvn clean install -Dtest=!LegacyTest#testFoo
# Exclude two test methods
mvn clean install -Dtest=!LegacyTest#testFoo+testBar
# Exclude a package with a wildcard (*)
mvn clean install -Dtest=!com.mycompany.app.Legacy*
```

To tell maven to include specific test:

```
# Include one file
mvn clean install -Dtest=AppTest
# Include one method
mvn clean install -Dtest=AppTest#testFoo
# Include two methods with the plus sign (+)
mvn clean install -Dtest=AppTest#testFoo+testBar
# Include multiple items comma separated and with a wildcard (*)
mvn clean install -Dtest=AppTest,Web*
# Include by Package with a wildcard (*)
mvn clean install -Dtest=com.mycompany.*.*Test
```

Note: We might need to escape "!" while using bash.

```
mvn clean install -Dtest=\!LegacyTest
```

To escape, we will have to use back slash(\)